# Is "Psychoactive effect" the correct term?

Tags: biology, medicine, terminology

I'm trying to describe an effect (in this case, a magic spell) that affects the mind, similar to caffeine or alcohol, but not a "substance". I want to use the correct scientific language if possible, is it correct to talk about a "psychoactive effect", or should that term only refer to actual substances (ie. drugs)? Is there a better term to use here?

Comment: Depending on the setting of your universe (medieval vs steam-punk, etc) it might make sense to use a less "modern" term. For example, a barbarian hero would probably not refer to anything as "psychoactive". Just a thought.

Comment: In this case the setting is modern, just with magic thrown in. Thanks for the thought, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### *It's technically correct. Which is the best kind of correct.*

Psychoactive simply means it affects the mind. Though it usually refers to the *effect of drugs*, it's accurate to use it to describe the *effect of mental magic*. The name for the magic itself though could be "psychoactive magic". Or, for something like a D&D setting, it would be a specific class of magic that acts on the brain like illusion or enchantment magic.